# warning in installation in fedena

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, fedena

I got following warning while installing fedena , how do I fix it

```
  rake/rdoctask is deprecated.  Use rdoc/task instead (in RDoc 2.4.2+)
    WARNING: Global access to Rake DSL methods is deprecated.  Please include
        ...  Rake::DSL into classes and modules which use the Rake DSL methods.
    WARNING: DSL method Spec::Rake::SpecTask#task called at C:/Fedena/lib/tasks/rspe
    c.rake:28:in `initialize'
```

Comment: Someone is using old methods in a Rakefile. What is your question?

Comment: i have followed all steps to install fedena as described in fedena project.org install site but i m getting error as rake db:create , rake deprecated msg occurs

Answer (score 0):

I had recently installed Fedena. The command "bundle exec rake db:create" worked for me! Glad to provide more info if needed!

Answer (score 0):

**1. Go to rakefile**

change `require 'rake/rdoctask'`

to     `require 'rdoc/task'`

**2. Go to Gemfile**

add `gem 'rdoc'`

**3. run Bundle**